# Trouble with posting jQuery to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to write a script that allows posting to a JSON file. For some reason the process is succeeding, but the JSON file isn't being written to.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  var data = {
    name: 'cool',
    drink: 'cool2',
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/api/orders',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function() {
      alert("Thanks!");
    }
  })
});
```

Here is my JSON code (/api/orders)

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"Ben","drink":"Americano w/ Creme"},
    {"id":2,"name":"Ben2","drink":"Americano w/ Creme2"},
    {"id":3,"name":"Ben3","drink":"Americano w/ Creme3"}
]
```

I can't figure out why Chrome is saying it is succeeding, but the code isn't posting to the JSON file.

Comment: The concept of "posting to a JSON file" doesn't make a lot of sense. What is the server-side environment here?

Comment: You need to get /pai/orders to return some result and have `success: function (data) {
        window.console&&console.log(data); 
 }` also why turn off async?

Comment: @Pointy I am using WAMP and am trying to use ajax post to write to a JSON file. Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, I'm totally new to jQuery.

Comment: @babin101, Well what are you using to parse the request and write the file??? That doesnt just magically happen.

Comment: Can you show us what code is on `/api/orders`

Comment: @prodigitalson like I said I just started learning jQuery yesterday. Can you explain that a little more basically please?

Comment: @void the /api/orders is the JSON file that I have above.

Comment: Why would anyone send a code to same file from where they are getting it. What do you want to do?

Comment: @babin101 Simply sending data to a URL does not write the data to a file. You need server side code for that... PHP, Ruby, Python, Node, something...

Comment: @void I'm trying to post a new line in /api/orders that says name: "cool" and drink: "cool2"

Comment: Wait @void so I need node.js?

Comment: You don't need to use JSON.stringify and be aware that `dataType` is to specify format for returned data from server

Comment: Doesnt have to be Node you could use whatever you are most comfortable with. You jsut need to use something on the server side to 1.) Get the data from the request, 2.) Open the existing JSON, 3.) Append the new JSON to the existing, 4.) write the file back to disk.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with your JavaScript. The JSON.stringify just concerts the data to a JSON string and passes it to the url. Your problem will be in the Url that it is posted to /Ali/orders. That looks like a directory to me instead of an API to handle the string. I could be wrong in that as certain technologies hide that stuff. Still you need to look at where the data is going to.